# Column Formatting with Caliburn.Mirco

Tags: wpf, datagrid, caliburn

Having a small issue with Column formatting being all wrong and not sure why, i can manage just fine without Caliburn but once thats introduced im having a whole load of issues.

thats the issue im having with regards to formatting in the screenshot below

https://www.epm-gaming.co.uk/screenshots/20150509151652336.png

The data is being bound to the datagrid by doing the following

https://www.epm-gaming.co.uk/screenshots/20150509151850572.png

Any idea what's going on there?

Comment: What do you mean by _formatting being all wrong_? Also instead of posting images of code can you post code/XAML? It's easier to read

Comment: formatting as in its cutting the GUID column down and leaving huge white spaces

,pastebin of the xaml

http://pastebin.com/KyhZDyGq

Comment: In the future, please post the code as part of your post. No screen shots of code, no external links.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have your columns configured to be equal widths (`ColumnWidth="*"`). Try making them auto size: `ColumnWidth="Auto"`

Comment: So the issue with that one is that it looks fine, apart from one random extra column that seems to be generating.